# Pseudo-terminal (pty) reporting Resource Temporarily Unavailable

Tags: c, linux, io, pty

I have a Pseudo-terminal slave that's giving me a read/write error of *Resource Temporarily Unavailable (11)*. I have been unable to solve this problem, but up until a week ago I didn't know anything pty's. So, I might be missing something obvious.

From what I have read, this can be caused by calling `read()` on a non-blocking pty. However, when I check the `F_GETFL` after I `open()` the slave pty, the value shows that it is a blocking file descriptor.

The output of `F_GETFL` shows that the `O_NONBLOCK` flag is disabled, and the `O_RDWR` flag is enabled:

```
printf("F_GETFL: %x\n", fcntl( slavefd, F_GETFL)); // outputs F_GETFL: 2
```

I have even tried treating `slavefd` as a non-blocking file by using `select()` to determine when it's ready. But, it just times out every time.

So, why does `read()` set errno to *Resource Temporarily Unavailable* if `slavefd` is set to blocking? Do the flags of `F_GETFL` look correct? What else can I try to narrow the cause of this problem?

**Update:** (more info)

I'm not sure yet, but I think the pty slave device node is being locked somehow by pppd. I have been told that you can echo into pty slave, which seems to be true except when pppd is using it.

**Update 2:** (code added)

```
if (argc!=2)
    return;

printf("opening %s\n", argv[1]);
slavefd = open(argv[1], O_RDWR );
if (slavefd < 0)
    return;
```

This update shows how I'm opening the slave device. Since I am using this application for debugging, I'm just directly using `argv[1]`.

**PROBLEM SOLVED:**

The slave node that I was attempting to read/write to was being modified by pppd. When pppd takes control of a tty/pty device, it changes the *line discipline* from `N_TTY` to `N_PPP`. This means that when when you `open()` and then `read()` or `write()` to the slave node, the PPP intermediate driver is being used instead of the TTY driver. So, a `read()` and `write()` boils down to a totally different function. Looking at the `N_PPP` driver I found the following. This answers my question as to why EAGAIN was being returned.

```
/*
 * Read does nothing - no data is ever available this way.
 * Pppd reads and writes packets via /dev/ppp instead.
 */
static ssize_t
ppp_asynctty_read(struct tty_struct *tty, struct file *file,
          unsigned char __user *buf, size_t count)
{
    return -EAGAIN;
}

/*
 * Write on the tty does nothing, the packets all come in
 * from the ppp generic stuff.
 */
static ssize_t
        ppp_asynctty_write(struct tty_struct *tty, struct file *file,
           const unsigned char *buf, size_t count)
{
    return -EAGAIN;
}
```

Comment: Do you have a receive timeout set? (set with setsockopt)

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but I'm met with the error `Socket operation on non-socket(88)`

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. I was just wondering if you had a timeout set because that's another case where read() can return EAGAIN. But it looks like that's not the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The slave node that I was attempting to read/write to was being modified by pppd. When pppd takes control of a tty/pty device, it changes the *line discipline* from `N_TTY` to `N_PPP`. This means that when when you `open()` and then `read()` or `write()` to the slave node, the PPP intermediate driver is being used instead of the TTY driver. So, a `read()` and `write()` boils down to a totally different function. Looking at the `N_PPP` driver I found the following. This answers my question as to why EAGAIN was being returned.

```
/*
 * Read does nothing - no data is ever available this way.
 * Pppd reads and writes packets via /dev/ppp instead.
 */
static ssize_t
ppp_asynctty_read(struct tty_struct *tty, struct file *file,
          unsigned char __user *buf, size_t count)
{
    return -EAGAIN;
}

/*
 * Write on the tty does nothing, the packets all come in
 * from the ppp generic stuff.
 */
static ssize_t
        ppp_asynctty_write(struct tty_struct *tty, struct file *file,
           const unsigned char *buf, size_t count)
{
    return -EAGAIN;
}
```